# Laravel 5 Google Maps API Unexpected number

Tags: laravel, google-maps-api-3, laravel-blade

I am using the google maps API to show a location. The lng/ltg values are stored in my DB. Unfortunately the values in my view are comma separated and an exception is thrown, because the values need to be separated with a point.

SequelPro shows me that the values are separated with points in my DB. 
It seems that blade is doing something else with the values.

```
var lat = 49,3987524;
```

What can I do to get `49.3987524` instead of `49,3987524`?

The error Message is:

```
4:491 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

This is my script:

```
var lat = {{$restaurant->lat}};
var lng = $restaurant->lng;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
center:{
  lat: lat,
  lng: lng
},
zoom: 15
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position:{
  lat:lat,
  lng: lng
},
map:map
});
```

Comment: Are you using var lng = $restaurant->lng; or var lng = {{ $restaurant->lng }}; ?

Comment: I am using {{$restaurant->lat}}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, In case somebody has a similar issue.
I solved it with {{str_replace(',','.',$restaurant->lat)}}.